# How do you set up StructureMap to use a Singleton with the Use<>.For<> syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I am using StructureMap with MVC3 I want to set it up to use a few of the objects as Singletons or to give them a Per Request life.   All of the examples I see out there are for an older syntax of StructureMap as when I try out the example I see that it is depricated.

How do you do this using the newer Use<>.For<> Syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using version 2.6.1, this should work:

```
For<IFoo>().Singleton().Use<Bar>();
```